# GtkTextView: How to change background color of current active blinking cursor line?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Depending on where the blinking cursor is, I would like the current active line have a different background color to make it clear which line I'm currently editing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use GtkSourceView instead of GtkTextView and set the [`highlight-current-line`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceView.html#GtkSourceView--highlight-current-line) property.